# About the function from R[x] to R that sends each polynomial to its leading coefficient

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let R be a commutative ring, and let h be the function from R[x] to R that sends each polynomial f(x) to its leading coefficient (an element of R). Is this a ring homomorphism? Is it a surjective map? Explain why or why not in each case.

Comment: What have you tried? Where did you get stuck? Please don't just ask us to do your homework for you.

Comment: a)this isn't homework   b)I've never done this before so i wouldn't know what to do so I'm not just asking for an answer  c) I'm having trouble getting started with this problem. I know how to prove homomorphism but I'm not sure where to exactly start

Answer (score 3):

For your first question, consider how this map behaves with respect to sum, and then perhaps also multiplication.

For the second question, given an *arbitrary* element of $a \in R$, can you find a polynomial whose leading coefficient is $a$? (Hint: *nearly* always.)

Comment: would a correct function for h be h(a0+a1x+…+anx^n)=a0

Comment: That's a much better behaved map! Proofs aren't difficult.

Comment: let a0 be in R 
we have a0+a1x+….+arxr in R[x]
such that h(a0+a1x+….+arxr)=a0 therefore it is onto

We have to show that h is a homomorphism.
Let p(x)= a0+a1x+….+anxn and q(x)= b0+b1x+….+bmxm
P(x)+q(x)=a0+b0+x(a1+b1)+…xm(am+bm)+…+anxn
P(x)q(x)=a0b0+(a0b0+b0a1)x+…
F(p(x)+q(x))=a0+b0
 =f(p(x))+f(q(x))
and f(p(x)q(x))= a0+b0
 =f(p(x))f(g(x))
so it is a homomorphism         am i on the right track here

Comment: I have slight trouble in reading what you write - please use $\LaTeX$ on this site. However, it looks right, except that when doing the product you have $a_{0} b_{0}$ of course, and not (obvious typo) $a_{0} + b_{0}$. And to show it is surjective, do not make things more complicated than they are, it is simply that if $a \in R$, then take the constant polynomial $a \in R[x]$, and you'll have $h(a) = a$. (The trouble with your version, an examiner might inquire what $r$ and the $a_{i}$ are, for $i > 0$.)

Comment: Ok i appreciate your help

Comment: You're welcome!